Gitlab Helm chart enable setting "New users set to external" in values.yaml file
I can't find a solution that would allow me to spin up a self-hosted GitLab instance with the option "New users set to external" enabled
Is there anyone knowledgeable to point me in the right direction to do this?
Have tried:

looking through the helm chart values.yaml file
looking through the helm charts itself
a way through rails console
API call without first having to generate a token by creating through the web interface

